# Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Find a constant for which $P(Z\geq c) = .1587$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I'm not sure how to do these type of problems. The solution only said the answer, and said from table A.2. I see the table, but I'm not sure how to lead up to the answer. I read the whole section on normal distribution and I can't find any example like this. I also checked the online examples similar to this, but they don't really explain what to do. If anyone could help, it would go a long way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(Z \geq c)$ is equivalent to $1 - P(Z < c)$. So $P(Z \geq c) = 0.1587$ can be rewritten as $$1 - P(Z < c) = 0.1587$$ or $P(Z < c) = 0.8417$ You can use the quantile function in a statistical package or a z table to see that the $c$ which satisfies the equation is $0.89535$. Rounding will get you your answer.

As for the second question, note that $P(0 \leq Z \leq c) = P(Z \leq c) - P(Z \leq 0) = 0.4772$. You can use the technique I described above to help solve this problem.

As for the final question, you can exploit the fact that $Z$ has a symmetric distribution and total area under its pdf is 1.

If the area between $-c$ and $c$ is $0.8664$ (that's $P(-c \leq Z \leq c)$), then there have to be two areas under the curve whose sum equals $1 - 0.8664 = 0.1336$, one on the left and one on the right. This implies that there has to be a $c$ such that $P(Z < c) = 0.0668 + 0.8664$. If you find that $c$ and round, you'll get your answer.

Comment: for the second question, I followed your example and plugged .5 in for $P(Z<=0)$ and added it to the other side to get $P(Z<=c) = .9772$ and looked that up to get c = 2, but the answer is negative 2. now I'm completely confused. Why didn't that work and what is the proper way to solve this problem ?

Comment: You're confused because you made an arithmetic error. $$P(Z \leq 0) - P( Z \leq c) = 0.4772$$ $$0.5 - P(Z \leq c) = 0.4772$$ $$P(Z \leq c) = 0.0228$$ What value of $c$ does that get you after rounding?

Comment: i was using the equation that you used in the original answer. I think maybe you reversed it?

Comment: can you also show me how you are able to make that equivalency?

Comment: i can see how $P(0≤Z≤c)=P(Z≤c)−P(Z≤0)=0.4772$ would be equivalent, because its the probability z is less than c on the curve - the probability z is less than 0 on the curve. but the answer comes out negative 2?

Comment: oh i see, the original question is $P(c<=Z<=0)$ but you wrote it with 0 first in the answer. This was still helpful though. thanks

Comment: Sure. For any continuous random variable $X$, $P(a \leq X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. So $P(c \leq Z \leq 0) = F(0) - F(c)$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $Z$. If you follow the steps in my previous comment, you should be able to get the answer.

(If you're stuck on calculating $P(Z \leq c)$, remember to use the quantile function in a statistical package of your choice or a z table.)

Comment: i was confused because you changed the original question from c<= Z <= 0 0<= Z <= c

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be $F(c) - F(0)$.

Comment: it's all good fam

Answer (score 0):

You should find a Z value such that $P(Z\ge c) = 0.1587 = 1 - P(Z\lt c).$
But there are several types of Z tables so the equation might depend on which table you use.

[image: Z>c table]

According to this table, you can find the value that you seek. 
But I strongly recommend you to study how to read these types of tables. The main purpose of these tables are to make your calculations easier. Normally those values are calculated by integration.